# Asp.net Mvc display list depending on User Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What i have initially on my App is a list of expensives that is created based on the Scarfolding System but that list is the same for each User, and what i want is that each user can create his own list of expensives and see his own data.

So in the expensive class i did this:

```
public class Despesa
{
    public int TipoDespesaId { get; set; }

    public int DespesaId { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descrição da Despesa")]
    [Required]
    public string DespesaDescricao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Valor")]
    [Required]
    public decimal DespesaValor { get; set; }

    public int TipoPagamentoId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [CustomValidation(typeof(Validator), "ValidateEndTimeRange")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public TipoDespesa TipoDespesa { get; set; }

    public TipoPagamento TipoPagamento { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Comentário")]
    public string Comentario { get; set; }

}
```

i just passed the UserId to the model and then in the Index controller of my Expensive View i did a linq query to compare the currentUserID to the Id of the expensive User here is my code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        String userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var despesas = db.Despesas.Include(d => d.TipoDespesa).Include(d => d.TipoPagamento).Where(d => d.UserId == userId);


        return View(despesas.ToList());
    }
```

what i need to know is what i am doing wrong cause i get a **ModalValidationException** when i try to acces my Expensive index view, why this still dont work?? by the way i add the string Id to the respect fields that i had create previously and did the migrations

Comment: Try specifying a [Key] attribute on `DespesaId`.

Also, you have `[Required]` attribute on some of your properties. I think this error is also thrown if them properties don't have any data in them, so either fill them properties with data or remove that attribute. You can also look into ModelState.IsValid property.

Comment: It looks like when the `Despesa` are created, it is failing the validation that you have specified. For a quick test, remove the `[Required]` attributes, `[DataType]`, `[CustomValidation]`. If it works, then you know that the data you are using to create the list of `Despesa` is breaking the validation.

Comment: has nothing to do with my Despesa look at this:                                       MSDiary.DAL.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
MSDiary.DAL.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.

Comment: Im trying to use the UserId from the default User Table, but is interfering with the other tables related to the User table dunno why and how to solve , cant get it why it is soo hard to save information from each user and display it :S